# Pandas dataframe rounding a series

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a pandas series like:

```
tempDF['A'] = dfOld.cl
```

where .cl is a string:

```
23.340000
24.350000
......
```

I would like to convert it to a float then round to 2 places

```
tempDF['A'] = round(dfOld.cl.astype(float),2)
```

output should be:

```
23.34
24.35
.....
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: what do you get when you run the code you provided, "tempDF['A'] = round(dfOld.cl.astype(float),2)" ? That code looks correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [pandas.Series.round](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html) function to accomplish this:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: dfOld = pd.DataFrame({'cl': ['0.014', '0.015', '0.016']})
dfOld.cl.apply(type).value_counts()  # prove that the values are strings

Out[2]:
<type 'str'>    3
dtype: int64

In [3]:
dfOld.cl.astype(float).round(decimals=2)

Out[3]:
0    0.01
1    0.02
2    0.02
Name: cl, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you're using `jupyter-notebook` you can type `df.cl.<tab>` to get a popup listing all of the methods bound to the `Series`, and you can run a cell containing the command `dfOld.cl.round?` to see the method signature.